# Как заставить вращаться 2 карусели одновременно?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, карусель

Всем привет. У меня на странице есть 2 карусели, в одно из которых включены стрелки и пагинация, а во второй нет. Подскажите, как можно "заставить" вращаться 2 карусели одновременно по клику на стрелках и пагинациях?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true
  });
  $("#owl-demo-2").owlCarousel({
    navigation: false,
    pagination: false
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .owl-item > div li,
#owl-demo-2 .owl-item > div li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div,
#owl-demo-2 .owl-item > div {
  padding: 0px 2px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <li>product 1</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 2</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 3</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 4</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 5</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 6</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
<ul>
  <div id="owl-demo-2" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <li>product 1</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 2</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 3</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 4</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 5</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 6</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

[ссылка на фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/TWtwt/361/)

Comment: Вроде вполне работают...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы порекомендовал для начала ознакомиться с [документацией](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) к данной библиотеке, в которой уже имеется вся необходимая информация с примерами. 
Конкретно в этом случае необходимо было воспользоваться методами .prev() и .next() которые будут отрабатывать при нажатии на кнопку, как это сделал я. Еще есть возможность использовать события и callback, но об этом уже можно прочесть в документации.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    pagination: true,

  });
  $("#owl-demo-2").owlCarousel({
    navigation: false,
    pagination: false
  });
  $('#next').click(function() {
    $('#owl-demo').data('owlCarousel').next();
    $('#owl-demo-2').data('owlCarousel').next();
  });
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    $('#owl-demo').data('owlCarousel').prev();
    $('#owl-demo-2').data('owlCarousel').prev();
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .owl-item > div li,
#owl-demo-2 .owl-item > div li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div,
#owl-demo-2 .owl-item > div {
  padding: 0px 2px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <li>product 1</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 2</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 3</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 4</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 5</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 6</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
<ul>
  <div id="owl-demo-2" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <li>product 1</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 2</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 3</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 4</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 5</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 6</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

[FiddleJS](http://jsfiddle.net/TWtwt/362/)